# jQuery postmessage cross domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I'm trying to get iframe content from third party website which is hosted in iframe within my application. I tried different things but without any success and the postMessage seems to be my last hope to get the content from the actual iFrame.

There's a textbox and button in the iframe which sends pin confirmation to the actual iframe owner. Now, once the button is clicked and the iframe is reloaded, if there's a 'Thank you' word within the iframe content that means that the transaction is successful.

I want somehow to detect the content with postMessage and get the actual content of the iframe and check if that word exists. Is this possible, and if so, how can I tackle it? This is what I have so far, actual div with the iframe:

```
<div class="row">
    <iframe id="frame" src = '@Model.SecureUrl' width = "100%" 
            height="360px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then in JS I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {                          
        $('#frame').load(function () {            
            if (iframe) {
               // use postMessage to get content?
            }           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "dd a message event Handler attached to the window object `$(window).on("message", function(e){ /* e.data contains the message string */})`

Comment: or write a 3 line proxy for your server

Comment: I think postMessage only works if your can add a message to the iframed page. From your post I assume you don't actually control the third party website so you can't add any messages that it would send?

Comment: For postmessages to work, the page in the iframe needs to listen and respond to postmessages.

Comment: @JuhaKangas correct I can't control the third party website. KevinB Do I have any other option how I can detect content change? I'm able to see the actual iframe content in FireBug, it's a pitty that I can't access it and FireBug can :)

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM ?

Comment: easyXDM has all kinds of fallbacks and it is cross-browser BUT it's kinda heavy.

Comment: @IgorEscobar will it work without being able to control the third party website?

Comment: @Laziale it will let you exchange information with third party websites but to CONTROL a third party via JavaScript you have to at least have CORS configurable correctly. I don't think you would be able to accomplish this without a tweek or two in that third party website.

Comment: I don't think any of these libraries will let you do it without adding something to the third party. So let me ask you this, do you know if the form post on the third party site requires the same domain? Perhaps you could post to this site from a form that you have on your site?

Comment: This is called XSS protection. I think you should drop that idea.

Comment: @JuhaKangas I can post from a different domain, but can you give me example how I can do the actual form post from my site, thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty much just copy the form being used in the iframe and post it to the same url used by that form